# Xml bulk Nodes appending issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to generate a million record xml file.For this i have a sample xml file with only one value set.Using this xml file fill ramdom values a million times.
I created a solutin but it is very time consuming one.My code is

```
try
        {
            label1.Text = "File creation in progress  ...";
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string sStartupPath = Application.StartupPath;
            string sName = "";
            int flag = 0;
            XmlDocument XmlFile = new XmlDocument();
            XmlFile.Load(sStartupPath + @"..\..\..\BankStatement.xml");
            XmlFile.Save(@"C:\XmlData\Bank.xml");
            XmlDocument XmlF = new XmlDocument();
            XmlF.Load(@"C:\XmlData\Bank.xml");
            long k = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            for (int j = 1; j < k; j++)
            {
                XmlTextReader objXmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(sStartupPath + @"..\..\..\BankStatement.xml");
                while (objXmlTextReader.Read())
                {
                    switch (objXmlTextReader.NodeType)
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            sName = objXmlTextReader.Name;
                            if (sName == "DataXml")
                            {
                                if (flag == 0)
                                    flag = 1;
                            }
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Text:
                            if (flag == 1)
                            {
                                XmlNodeList elemList = XmlFile.GetElementsByTagName(sName);
                                for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    if (elemList[i].Name == "Name")
                                        elemList[i].InnerXml = generateNames();
                                    else if (elemList[i].Name == "EmailID")
                                        elemList[i].InnerXml = generatemailids();
                                    else
                                        elemList[i].InnerXml = rnd.Next(500000).ToString();
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                            sName = objXmlTextReader.Name;
                            if (sName == "DataXml")
                            {
                                if (flag == 1)
                                    flag = 0;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                XmlDocument dd = new XmlDocument();
                dd.LoadXml(XmlFile.InnerXml); 
                XmlNodeList node=dd.GetElementsByTagName("Customers");
                XmlDocumentFragment xfrag = XmlF.CreateDocumentFragment();
                xfrag.RemoveAll();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                {
                    xfrag.InnerXml = node[i].InnerXml;                        
                    XmlF.DocumentElement.FirstChild.AppendChild(xfrag);                        
                }

                XmlF.Save(@"C:\XmlData\Bank.xml");

            }

            label1.Visible = false;
            MessageBox.Show("File creation success..!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label1.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured");
        }
```

Please give me a better solution.

Comment: I bet that's not only time consuming, but uses a lot of RAM.

Comment: That's because you are holding the entire document in memory, even nodes that you have already processed :-)  See my answer for a more efficient way.

Comment: yes,But i tried it with the save in only once.Using that the generated nodes values are identical.So tried this way

Answer (score 2):

The fastest method I know to write XML (short of building the XML fragments manually) is to use [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d1k42hb.aspx)

> The XmlWriter class is an abstract base class that provides a
>   forward-only, write-only, non-cached way of generating XML streams. It
>   can be used to build XML documents that conform to the W3C Extensible
>   Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (fourth edition) recommendation and the
>   Namespaces in XML recommendation.

[MSDN has a walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx3wa6ka.aspx) on how to use the abstract XmlWriter class.

Comment: +1. For such a big XML creating in-memory copy will be hard (especially in x86 case, may be ok on x64). Reading would not be much fun either :).

Comment: Yep.  I came across that very issue not long ago.  x64 gives you the memory space, but it's still very slow, and if you start to swap... :-(

Answer (score 0):

For writing large XML files you should use [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx).